# GetVaryByCustomString method is not called

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, outputcache

Have a problem on production server. On local and test servers this problem is not reproduced.

.NET 4.5, Sitecore 7.2.

Several user controls have the following directive:

```
<%@ OutputCache VaryByParam="*"  Duration="300" VaryByCustom="VaryByUrl" %>
```

Note: corresponding sitecore sublayouts have caching is turned off.

Method in Global.asax:

> ```
>     public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
>     {
>         switch (custom.ToLower())
>         {
>             case "varybyurl":
>                 return context.Request.Url.DnsSafeHost + context.Request.RawUrl + OutputCacheKey;
>         }
>
>         return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
>     }
> ```

Previously caching was working normally. But since recent times, it was broken suddenly (but only on live server). Its behavior:

- Page #1 with user control (that have mentioned directive) is loaded with some information (e.g. "Text A").
- Then I am opening another page #2 with the same control but with another data (which should have "Text B"), but "Text A" is shown on this control on this page.
- Only after 300 seconds, after refreshing the page #2, it shows "Text B".
- I was trying to add the logging into GetVaryByCustomString and no logs was received on live server, so it means that method was not called.

Maybe someone has any idea why it works in such way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cause of problem is found!

**Global.asax** file was absent on live server.

It was not delivered during last build for some reason.

Current issue could be closed :)